# Requested JSON parse failed (ajax) + zf2

Tags: ajax, json, zend-framework2

I have a problem when trying to access a JSON Variable sent by ajax to php.
Envío la varible "correo":

```
<script>
$("#recuperar").click(function () {
    var  url1 = "<?php echo $this->url('login',array('controller'=>'Login', 'action'=>'recuperar' )) ?>";   
    var consulta = $("#correo").val();
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: url1,
        data: {"correo": consulta}, 

        dataType: "json",

        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#mostrar").empty(data);
            $("#mostrar").append(data['error']);
        }
    });
});
```

my controller:

```
public function recuperarAction() {
    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

    $correo = $_REQUEST['correo'];
    print_r($correo);
```

When I try to `print_r($email)` returns me this error: Requested JSON parse failed.

This also goes for if to `print_r(some_value)`, if I try to print any data returns me the same error.

Appreciate the help, Sorry my English is pure Google Translation

Answer (score 0):

First you should set your datatype to `application/json`. The `json` you currently have is not a correct `Content-Type` declaration for `json` data.

If that doesn't solve your issues try to validate your `json` data with a `json` validator like for example **[json lint](http://jsonlint.com/)**.

Comment: Thanks for responding, you Might explain me how to configure the application for Json data. Thank you very much, really am new to ZF2 and Doctrine2.